# How to integrate draw.io into java website?

Tags: java, hibernate, struts, draw.io

I have a website build using struts and Hibernate, I need to integrate draw.io in the webpage and RECORD the diagram made using draw.io into database and also show it in the webpage.
Can anyone suggest how to integrate and RECORD diagrams made with draw.io into a webpage ?

Comment: I have seen that there is a custom Plugin for embedding draw.io with Wordpress, is there similar way to embed it in javascript ?

Comment: Your question is too broad and likely to be closed. But you might look at https://support.draw.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=8945851.